# Is this question "too localized", or maybe "too special"? Should it be closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I just saw *[Sample Code to Demonstrate Bug with Reflection API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45241046/sample-code-to-demonstrate-bug-with-reflection-api)*:

> link to oracle bug report ... Could somebody demonstrate this bug with a simple code, just for me to check if my code is a victim of this bug?

Now I am wondering: is this a valid question? If not, what to do about it?

(And yes, I am kind if wondering if such a question would have closed as "too localized" whilst that category existed, but that is not the real point here.)

Comment: No, we got rid of that close reason for a reason.  There's no need to dwell on the past.  Evaluate it in the now instead.

Comment: Not sure if you noticed, but I **first** asked *Now I am wondering - is this a valid question? If not, what to do about*.

Comment: It might be useful to you to remove the "localized" bits then.  Since that doesn't exist now, it'd only serve to confuse others in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thing is, this question has a *chance* of being salvageable.  The OP is just asking this in the wrong order.

The main issue is that the OP is afflicted by what they *believe* to be a bug in the JVM.  Instead of posting their code for us to independently verify and test, they're asking us to provide *them* code so that *they* can validate their assertions.

The issue with this is that it's burden of proof; as is, we can't write that kind of code for them on-demand, and so it'd be suitable to close as "too broad".  However, it's *not* too broad for them to ask something analogous to, "What's wrong with this code?" in the same vein as a debugging problem.

I'll let the OP know about this Meta discussion, and ask them to reverse the order of their question.  It *could* be on-topic, it just needs to be rephrased.

Comment: For the record: there is already a comment with a link to this question on that other question.

Comment: @GhostCat:  One that *wasn't* written by me?

Comment: The one written by me starting with *I am saying that I find your question so special that I am asking my self if it "belongs" here. And as I got curious about, I put up a question on meta.* ... that meta being a link. So, yes. Exactly. One not written by you.

Comment: @GhostCat:  Guess I didn't see it.  The link was fairly tiny.  Okay then!

Comment: Hmm, I sort of follow the logic here, but in a way it seems like you are making the question *more* localized, rather than less. Isn't it more general and therefore more useful to simply ask for code that would reproduce a bug, than to present some specific code and ask whether it is vulnerable to a bug? What if I have code that is *similar* to the code in the question, but subtly different. The Q&A then becomes less useful to me, because I don't know if the subtle differences in our code are important.

Comment: @CodyGray:  The problem there is that, as presented initially, the problem is one that involves debugging.  Initially yes, this may make it more localized to that individual, but if the OP can isolate the specific code that reproduces the JVM bug, *and* it's actually a JVM bug, then it would apply broadly.  If it weren't a bug, then it'd fall into the same bucket of debugging questions we already have here, which do have their own value and niches here.  The key here is **isolation**.  The OP has to do their diligence in isolating their code which they believe exhibits the bug.

Comment: So, would you say that "Can you provide repro code for this bug?" is completely off-topic? Because I'm not sure I agree with that blanket statement, and it kinda seems like that's what he's asking.

Comment: @CodyGray:  Suppose it turned out *not* to be a JVM bug.  It'd be nice to be able to assert that *before* we invested any kind of time authoring any kind of demonstration code of an actual JVM problem.  It feels like a stealth XY problem in that the OP has said that there's a bug, but we can't validate that claim since we haven't seen their code to really *see* if there's a bug.  Now that the OP has actually posted an answer, it seems to be a symptom of [the diamond problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29758344/1079354) with interfaces.  Better to ask the OP questions first than to guess.